# Backbone - Can't get attributes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a function which does a fetch, it returns successful and sets the data.

But I can't work out how to get the data out of the model again.

```
fetchAcceptedTerms: function () {
  var self = this;
  this.appAcceptedTerms = new T1AppAcceptedTerms();
  this.acceptedTerms = new AppAcceptedTerms();

  this.acceptedTerms.fetch({
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      if (data.meta.status === 'success') {
        self.appAcceptedTerms.set(data.data);
      }
    }
  });

  console.log(self.appAcceptedTerms);
  console.log(self.appAcceptedTerms.attributes);
},
```

See output in console:
http://s32.postimg.org/ssi3w7wed/Screen_Shot_2016_05_20_at_14_17_21.png

As you can see:

- `console.log(data);` returns the data as expected
- `console.log(self.appAcceptedTerms);` the data is set correctly as we can see it in the log
- `console.log(self.appAcceptedTerms.attributes);` isn't working properly and returns `Object {}`

Can someone help on how to get all of the attributes out?

Thanks

Comment: According to [backbone docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch), the `success` callback receives `(model, response, options)` as arguments (presuming you are doing `model.fetch`), if you want `appAcceptedTerms` to have the same attributes as `acceptedTemrs` then please check by replacing the line `self.appAcceptedTerms.set(data.data)` with `self.appAcceptedTerms.set(data.toJSON())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fetch operation is asynchronous, so you need to check for your attributes after the fetch operation has completed.  Does the below output your attributes as expected?

```
fetchAcceptedTerms: function () {
  var self = this;
  this.appAcceptedTerms = new T1AppAcceptedTerms();
  this.acceptedTerms = new AppAcceptedTerms();

  this.acceptedTerms.fetch({
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      if (data.meta.status === 'success') {
        self.appAcceptedTerms.set(data.data);
        console.log(self.appAcceptedTerms);
        console.log(self.appAcceptedTerms.attributes);
      }

    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Yeah sorry was being dumb :)